# Chrome blocks mouse interaction for autofilled input

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, autofocus, final-form

I have a simple registration form based on Material UI and React Final Form.
Email and password inputs are filled automatically by Chrome autofill if it is possible. The email field has autofocus on it. When the form is autofilled, inputs become "blocked" for mouse interaction (I cannot not place or see caret, cannot select part of email, no autofocus is applied), yet it is available for drag-and-drop copy with mouse and keyboard interaction. I have no idea how can this happen and do not understand, how to provide code for reproduction. Maybe some autofocus issue? Hope that anyone could help.

Comment: Ciao, could you post some code? Or maybe a codesandbox (would be perfect :) )?

Comment: Is this solved? In that case how? I have the same issue using Vue.js and Stencil.